What happens to the operators (matmul, etc) when a model is quantized?
Model parameter quantization talks about how to reduce the precision of model weights such as in Quantization or Introduction to Quantization cooked in  with ‍.
But, what about the operator functions such as Matmul or Softmax or Cross Entropy Loss? Do they need to be altered to handle to int8 when quantizing to int8? How about the input data X? Do we need to quantize X so that they are also int8?
